# Python 3 [TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer] when working with sockets

Tags: python, string, sockets, python-3.x, byte

I run the script with python3 in the terminal but when I reach a certain point in it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 50, in <module>
    client()
  File "client.py", line 45, in client
    s.send(bytes((msg, 'utf-8')))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is the code it refers to.

```
else :
    # user entered a message
    msg = sys.stdin.readline()
    s.send(bytes((msg, 'utf-8')))
    sys.stdout.write(bytes('[Me] '))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I read the official documentation for bytes() and another source

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes

http://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/

but I am no closer to understanding how to fix this. I realise that my msg is a string and I need an integer, but I am confused about how to convert it. Can you please help me, or direct me to a source that will help me?

Edit 1: I changed the line

```
s.send(bytes((msg, 'utf-8')))
```

to

```
s.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
```

but now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 50, in <module>
    client()
  File "client.py", line 46, in client
    sys.stdout.write(bytes('[Me] '))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Edit 2: According to @falsetru updated answer.
Using bytes literal gives me

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: You have double-wrapped `bytes`'s arguments in parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
s.send(bytes((msg, 'utf-8')))
```

as:

```
s.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
```

In other words, pass a string and an encoding name instead of a passing a tuple to `bytes`.

---

**UPDATE** accoridng to question change:

You need to pass a string to `sys.stdout.write`. Simply pass a string literal:

```
sys.stdout.write('[Me] ')
```

Comment: Lol, that's funny. Auto-tupling trouble at its finest.

Comment: @Adonis, I updated the answer again. In short, I should say `string literal`, not a `bytes literal`.